# WSO2 - Tenant based logging

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

How do we ensure tenant based logging in WSO2?
We do not want logs from different customers getting mingled. Essentially, what we are looking for is completely different directories for each tenant's logs. 
I have read a fair bit of documentation for the same and there does not seem to be an out of the box solution.

Any tips is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs are separate in memory, so you may login to the carbon console as a tenant admin and check Monitor -> System Logs to see the logs dedicated to that specific tenant.

However, there is no OOTB solution to dividing the text based logs by tenant.